# MySql find friends of Player X from table Games

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

1) I need to: **"Find All players that play the same game of Player '55' for games' id bigger than 2"**

The tables are as in the picture below:

[image]

I tried many statements but they produce wrong result:

```
SELECT Games.id, Players.id from Games, Players 
WHERE Players.id='55' and Games.id > 2;
```

2) Additionally what would you do if I say that I need to select the same as before, where the "**Game's id are only the last 2 in Descending order**" (i.e. only games with id 3 and 4 in this case, but that could be different for other cases). I can only think of comparing Games.id with a number from user input, but some of you might know another way...

Can someone help me please? Thank you!

**EDIT**:

1) `SELECT b.id_player, b.id_game FROM Players a, Players b WHERE a.id_player = '55' AND b.id_game = a.id_game AND b.id_player <> '55' AND a.id_game > 2;`

2) Option 1 works for question 1, but question 2 would require a TOP clause which doesn't work for me.

How can I use LIMIT or TOP to achieve the same as `a.id_game > 2`? I want only the results from the last 2 ID_GAMEs, in this case are id=3 and id=4...

**EDIT:** 
Well never mind, I've got the 1st question. I will just put LIMIT to a fixed number. Thanks for the help

Comment: seems like homework.  try the IN () clause.

Comment: `select id_player, id_game from players where id_game in (select id_game from players where id_player = 55 and id_game > 2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self-join. I too can't test this right now - will do a SQL fiddle in a moment, but it should be something like:

```
SELECT b.id_player, b.id_game 
FROM Players a, 
     Players b 
WHERE a.id_player = '55' 
AND   b.id_game   = a.id_game 
AND   b.id_player <> '55' 
AND   a.id_game > 2
order by b.id_game
limit 2;
```

Comment: Looks nice, but I made a few changes

Comment: This will only return 2 rows, no matter how many players are playing the games number 55 is playing, this query does not solve the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Players.* 
FROM 
(SELECT id_game 
    FROM Players 
    WHERE id_player = 55 
    ORDER BY id_game DESC 
    LIMIT 2) 
AS A JOIN Players ON Players.id_game = A.id_game 
WHERE id_player <> 55
```

EDIT. LIMIT in subqueries is not implemented in mysql yet (original post), the proposal alternative by mysql itself it is to use a query like this one, tested this time.

Comment: I am using MySql TOP 2 seems not to work for me (works without), also I wanted to see only Player '55' friends (friends in the sense that they play the same game)

Comment: This will not work, I can't accept your answer because the syntax is wrong, also LIMIT 2 will only display the last 2 rows not all results with last 2 game_ids. But I really appreciate your help. Thanks very much for your time

Comment: Now it is working, tested, and you are wrong about the LIMIT, it was and is only in the subquery, so it filters only last two games for player 55, then main query will return all players for those games (any number, not limited) except 55.

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely work.

```
SELECT a.* FROM Players a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id,id_player,id_game 
            FROM players 
            WHERE id_game > 2 AND id_player = 55
           ) b 
ON a.id_game = b.id_game
WHERE a.id_player != 55;
```